# Magento Special Price To Date don't work probably

Tags: magento

> I am working on **Magento CE6.1** , I have new task to apply special
>   offers on specific products on date later on . I noticed that some
>   products had the special offers at the same date not the date which I
>   added on Special Price To Date .

[ٍSpecial Offer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzctM.png)

> **Could you please help me to solve this issue ?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: From and to dates are not valid. Check your logs for more information